# Perl - can I use subs from a module which aren't exported

Tags: perl

Maybe the answer is trivially negative, but just in case: is there any way I can use a sub from a module if it is not exported?

The following code would work if `SomePackage` exports `some_sub`:

```
use lib '/home/something';
use SomePackage qw( some_sub );

&some_sub(arg);
```

Is there a way to use `some_sub` if it's not exported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is trivially positive. Qualify the sub name with the sub's package:

```
use Some::Package ();

Some::Package::some_sub($arg);
```

Comment: This will usually, but not always work. Using the fully qualified name will work in most sane cases when the `Export` module is used by `Some::Package`, but if importing is done manually (or with `Sub::Exporter`) no such 1:1 relationship between exported symbols and entries in the package's namespace has to exist – it might be using anonymous subroutines under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* of course, just by calling them with their fully-qualified name.

```
Some::Module::function( $args, @here )
```

The larger question though is whether or not you should. Perl doesn't enforce visibility at the language level; that is left to programmers. If a module has a function that it doesn't export and doesn't document, then the expectation is that you shouldn't be calling it. If it's internal implementation, it might be subject to unstable change at any time, breaking your code that relied on being able to call it.